# Angularjs isolated scope dynamically pass attribute name

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to make a directive which make carousal from controller data

here is my

---------- controller---------

```
myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){

                $scope.outfit = {
                    name : 'guess',
                    price : '100$'
                };

                $scope.myLook= {
                    name : 'guess',
                    price : '100$'
                };

                $scope.tabs = [
                    { title:"THE RUNWAY" , data : 'outfit'},
                    { title:"MY LOOK",  data : 'myLook'},
                ];
    );
```

------My Directive--------

```
myApp.directive('bxSlider',function(){
     return {
          restrict : 'E',
          templateUrl : require.toUrl('../partials/bxSlider.html'),
          replace: true,
          scope: {
                outs : "="
          }
    }
});
```

------My Template--------

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="tab in tabs">
       <bx-slider outs="{{ tab.data }}" /> 
        // i want my outs param value as the output of tab.data as param 
        // i.e outfit or mylook  **how can i do that is there any workaround**
    </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/_anil/TLYBh/4)

Comment: what issue you are facing ?

Comment: m not able to get data from controller inside  my directive scope
i.e if i pass <bx-slider outs="myLook" /> or <bx-slider outs="outfit" /> it works, but when i using dynamic name as <bx-slider outs="{{ tab.data }}" /> which will evaluate to  "outfit" or "myLook" isn't work

Comment: you say it's not working but aren't showing code in directive that causes problem. How are you trying to work with attributes? Create a demo in plunker with code you are trying

Comment: its working [http://jsfiddle.net/7CG4Q/1](http://jsfiddle.net/7CG4Q/1)

Comment: @charlietfl it's not working can u see fiddle please

Comment: I don't see link to any fiddle you've added, or any update to directive code in the question

Comment: @charlietfl http://jsfiddle.net/_anil/TLYBh/4/

Comment: put the link in question so others can see it also...will give you better chance of getting people to look at it

Comment: so what is wrong with solution provided by @Ravi?

Comment: @charlietfl it's not correct as <div>{{outs}}</div> is output is "outfit" but my Parent Scope data is  {
                    name : 'guess',
                    price : '100$'
                };
i cant able to assess name or price property in directive template 
<div>{{outs.name}}</div>

Comment: but that's not what you showed in your demo...there is no `name` in data in that demo. If you want help you need to do a littl more work to put together a proper demo that more reflects your situation...we can't make guesses what you are working with

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wilsonrufus/7CG4Q/3/ try this anil sir

Answer (score 0):

Its working check it out. I have changed the `scope variable` of `directive`
[Fiddle Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/7CG4Q/1)